# How to display the details based on month and year in C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am kind of new to c# MVC. I want to display the image and its contents or details based on month and year. How do I do that? Right now I am displaying all. But I want to display something like this:

My images are in different table called "photos". and date content are in diffrent table called "article".

> 2018
>
> July
>
> [Image ]   [Hello World]
>
> June
>
> [Image]  [Hello world!!! Hello world]

View:

```html
@model Magzine.Models.Article


<div class="row">

    @if (Model.Image.Count > 0)
            
     

{

        
@foreach (var img in Photos)
        {
           
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <img class="Img" src="=@Url.Content(img.img_url) "  /></a>
            </div>
       }

     }               
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <strong>@Model.date</a></strong>
                <strong>@Model.content</a></strong>
            </div>    
        </div>
```

Database table:
[image]

Comment: Do you want all items grouped by month - So you might have more than 1 image below "June"? Or do you only need to display the month in letters and not worry about grouping?

Comment: Yes I have more than one image under June and I want to display month in letters and group all the images based on month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an idea. Your model is a list of article.
So you need to group your list by Year and Month of the article.

```
Model.GroupBy(item => item.date.Month)
```

Foreach group, you should print the name of the month by the method below and his collection associated.

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(group.Key)
```

But I recommend you to do these actions in the server and return a model containing the refined data. No action calculation on View, just `if` and `for` are acceptable.

**View:**

```
   @foreach (var groupYear in Model.GroupBy(item => item.data.Year).Select(group => new { Key = group.Key, Items = group.ToList() })
       {{Key}}
        @foreach (var groupMonth in Items.GroupBy(item => item.date.Month))
             <span>{CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(groupMonth.Key)};
             @foreach (var article in groupMonth )    
             {
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-2">
                          <img class="Img" src="=@Url.Content(article.img_url)"/></a>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-10">
                          <strong>@article.date</a></strong>
                          <strong>@article.content</a></strong>
                      </div>
                  </div>
    }     

      }
```

Comment: You probably need another loop for years.

Comment: Sorry I added wrong code for view. I have updated my view code. can you please look into my view code

Comment: I am not  running foreach to get date and article. I missed to add image is stored in different table and article and date in different table.  so how do i modify your code ?